# Every nonnegative real analytic function is the square of a real analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, radicals, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ an analytic nonnegative real function that may have zeros. There always exists an analytical real function $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f =g^2$?

If $f>0$ then this is true since the square root is analytic on $(0,\infty)$. But when $f$ has some zeros? I imagine that one can inquire the order of the zero locally since they are isolated, and work on the Taylor series, but I'm not totally convinced.

Notice that the other similar questions on this site only asks for strictly positive functions or complex square roots.

Comment: If the function has zeros, check their order. An odd order zero must be positive **and** negative in a neighborhood.

Comment: @Somos I know all the zeros must have even order, but is that enough to conclude?

Comment: Mention this important detail in your question. I suggest use [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

Comment: If $f(a)>0$ then, by continuity, $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ near $a$, so $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is analytic near $a$. If $f(a)=0$ then, for some integer $n>0$, $f(x)=(x-a)^{2n}g(x)$ for all $x$ near $a$, where $g(x)$ is analytic and $g(a)\neq0$. In fact $g(a)>0$ since $f(x)$ is non-negative near $a$. Thus $f(x)=\big((x-a)^n\sqrt{g(x)}\big)^2$ is the square of an analytic function near $a$. Now the only question is how to combine these local square roots, which may have conflicting signs, into a single global square root of $f$.